# CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin not working in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors

I am trying to send ajax post request from my rails app (https://myrails.app.com) to my node js app (https://mynodejs.app)

Below are the contents of my app.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://myrails.app.com");
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  if('options' == req.method()){
    res.status(200);
  }else{
    next();
  }
});

require('./middlewares/middleware')(app);

process.on('uncaughtException', (ex) => {
  console.log(ex.message);
  process.exit(1);
});

module.exports =  app;
```

below is my **server.js** file

```
const serverProtocol = ['production', 'staging'].includes(process.env.NODE_ENV) ? require('http') : require('https');

const app = require('./app');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3002;
const server = serverProtocol.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);
```

I still get an error on my rails app, this is what i see in my browser console

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://mynodejs.app (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)
```

Any help on how to fix this would be really great. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the headers in the browser debugger console? Are the headers present there?

Comment: Can you show how `app.js` is imported and used in your bin/www file? (there's also this: [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors))

Comment: hi @Paul, i checked the browser console, but don't see the response header set via the node js app. This is what i seeHTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Tue, 26 May 2020 22:06:12 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 226
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

Comment: Hi @ChrisG, sorry i am new to node.js and did not fully understand your questions. i dont have a bin/www file

Comment: Is the above code all you have? Which server are you running it on? Without at least an [`app.listen()`](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) call, that code cannot answer requests.

Comment: @ChrisG i have updated the question with my server.js file

Comment: Just to be sure: Have you checked that the uploaded running node app is uptodate and not some old version and that the lines in app.js are processed?

Comment: @Paul, yes i did verify it. I did add console.log statements and see it printed too

Comment: I used your code and got it to work. 1. `if ('options' == req.method) {` (method is a property, not a function) 2. I added a very simple route `app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send("hello"));` (your server never sends anything back, which causes the error I guess)

Comment: @ChrisG, i used `if ('options' == req.method)` but still does not work, also i added ` res.status(200).json('hello');` for the same if statement but it still does not wokr

Comment: @ChrisG, wierd thing i see if the code never comes inside `req.method == options`,could there be some other issue?

Comment: How are you deploying it? Heroku?

Comment: @ChrisG AWS, using kubernetes

Comment: I don't know what to tell you; it worked for me (I had to comment out the middleware line). My suggestion would be to start from the hello world example so you get a response, then go from there, this way you'll at least know exactly which addition/change broke the code.